# How to populate an array with incrementally increasing values Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, project

I'm attempting to solve http://projecteuler.net/problem=1.

I want to create a method which takes in an integer and then creates an array of all the integers preceding it and the integer itself as values within the array.

Below is what I have so far. Code doesn't work.

```
def make_array(num)
  numbers = Array.new num  
  count = 1

  numbers.each do |number|
    numbers << number = count
    count = count + 1
  end

  return numbers    
end

make_array(10)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`(1..num).to_a` is all you need to do in Ruby.

`1..num` will create a `Range` object with start at `1` and end at whatever value `num` is. `Range` objects have `to_a` method to blow them up into real `Arrays` by enumerating each element within the range.

For most purposes, you won't actually need the `Array` - `Range` will work fine. That includes iteration (which is what I assume you want, given the problem you're working on).

That said, knowing how to create such an `Array` "by hand" is valuable learning experience, so you might want to keep working on it a bit. Hint: you want to start with an empty array (`[]`)  instead with `Array.new num`, then iterate something `num.times`, and add numbers into the `Array`. If you already start with an `Array` of size `num`, and then push `num` elements into it, you'll end up with twice `num` elements. If, as is your case, you're adding elements *while you're iterating the array*, the loop never exits, because for each element you process, you add another one. It's like chasing a metal ball with the repulsing side of a magnet.

Comment: can't figure out how to past block code but yes the changes worked. thank you

Comment: @Ali - Another similar method you can use is: `1.upto(num).to_a`.

Comment: I appreciate the tip Mischa. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the Euler Question:

```
(1 ... 1000).to_a.select{|x| x%3==0 || x%5==0}.reduce(:+) # => 233168
```

Sometimes a one-liner is more readable than more detailed code i think.

Assuming you are learning Ruby by examples on ProjectEuler, i'll explain what the line does:

```
(1 ... 1000).to_a
```

will create an array with the numbers one to 999. Euler-Question wants numbers *below* 1000. Using three dots in a Range will create it without the boundary-value itself.

```
.select{|x| x%3==0 || x%5==0}
```

chooses only elements which are divideable by 3 or 5, and therefore multiples of 3 or 5. The other values are discarded. The result of this operation is a new Array with only multiples of 3 or 5.

```
.reduce(:+)
```

Finally this operation will sum up all the numbers in the array (or reduce it to) a single number: The sum you need for the solution.

What i want to illustrate: many methods you would write by hand everyday are already integrated in ruby, since it is a language from programmers for programmers. be pragmatic ;)

Comment: I upvoted for the oneliner, but given that OP has trouble with populating an array with a sequence, I believe functional style might be a bit over his head...

Comment: It is never too early to think in a functional style. On our university we even learned a haskell before any imperative or OO language... also, writing expressions instead of a bunch of simple instructions should help a beginner to read what the code actually does, exspecially when the codebase grows. Functional style is like describing your Problem to a mathematican, imperative style is like giving instructions to an idiot :D

Comment: I agree, for Haskell and Scheme. When you learn them, you start with patterns/lambdas and recursion and build your functional tools, so you understand what they do. Ruby, while quite powerful functionally, is not syntactically and semantically as lean. You will never start as purely, and will go to the standard library. To use functional style in Ruby, you need to know about blocks and `Enumerable` and that `:+` is a symbol and why a symbol works as an argument to `reduce`... And let me just note that `.to_a` is a waste of space and time, since `select` will work directly on a `Range` :P

Comment: Yay, thanks to that note about to_a, didn't think of that :) I'll leave it in my answer for now, to make it clear to the OP that i use a simple Array structure.

Comment: Yes, I am going through the problems on project euler to become more comfortable coding in Ruby. I like minimalist code, but at this point in my learning process reading one liner code snippets is a bit confusing. Thanks for breaking it down Hisako. For the past week I have been going through the basics of solving these problems on my own. I occasionally read other's solutions and look up terms that are unfamiliar, but only after solving the problem myself. That sums up my learning strategy at this point. Any tips in accelerating the learning process will be well received. Cheers.

Comment: Ah okay. Instead of Project Euler you may have a look at http://rubeque.com/ . There are some really nive questions for beginners that help learning the language and conventions well while you're trying to solve them.